# How to pivot multiple columns at the same time?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame with exam questions organized as you see below in `input`.
I'm trying to organize it in a tidy way as displayed in `output`.

In `input` you can see student's `ID`, their answer to the specific item `suffix = ".text"`, their score for that specific item `suffix = ".score"`, and their `total` score.

### Input

```
library(tibble)

input <- tribble(
     ~ID, ~i1.text, ~i1.score, ~i2.text, ~i2.score, ~total,
  "Mark",      "A",        0L,      "B",        1L,     1L,
  "Mary",      "C",        1L,      "D",        0L,     1L,
  "John",      "A",        0L,      "B",        1L,     1L,
  "Abby",      "C",        1L,      "B",        1L,     2L
  )
```

I need to pivot the data to look like the one below.

I'm quite certain that I can do that with `pivot_longer()` but I'm quite lost.

### Expected Output

```
output <- tribble(
     ~ID, ~item, ~text, ~score, ~total,
  "Mark",  "i1",   "A",     0L,     1L,
  "Mark",  "i2",   "B",     1L,     1L,
  "Mary",  "i1",   "C",     1L,     1L,
  "Mary",  "i2",   "D",     0L,     1L,
  "John",  "i1",   "A",     0L,     1L,
  "John",  "i2",   "B",     1L,     1L,
  "Abby",  "i1",   "C",     1L,     2L,
  "Abby",  "i2",   "B",     2L,     2L
  )

output

# A tibble: 8 × 5
  ID    item  text  score total
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <int> <int>
1 Mark  i1    A         0     1
2 Mark  i2    B         1     1
3 Mary  i1    C         1     1
4 Mary  i2    D         0     1
5 John  i1    A         0     1
6 John  i2    B         1     1
7 Abby  i1    C         1     2
8 Abby  i2    B         2     2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer` with `names_sep` as `.` - the column 'item' return the prefix part of the column names before the `.` and the `.value` will return the values of the column with the suffix part of the column name after the `.`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(input, cols = contains("."), 
    names_to = c("item", ".value"), names_sep = "\\.")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 5
  ID    total item  text  score
  <chr> <int> <chr> <chr> <int>
1 Mark      1 i1    A         0
2 Mark      1 i2    B         1
3 Mary      1 i1    C         1
4 Mary      1 i2    D         0
5 John      1 i1    A         0
6 John      1 i2    B         1
7 Abby      2 i1    C         1
8 Abby      2 i2    B         1
```

Comment: Could you add to your response an explanation about why `names_sep` use `”\\.” ` instead of just “.”?

Comment: @RuamPimentel by defaut, it is regex mode and `.` can match any character in `regex`.  Escaping is done to read it literally

Answer (score 2):

Here is an similar but alternative approach using `names_pattern`:

Explanation: `(.*)\\.(.*)` is regex:

`()` captures a group

`.` captures any character

`*` is a quantifier means 0 or more

`\\` Escape character

The regular expression means:
any amount of character followed by a dot followed by any amount of character. This regex matches your column names:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

input %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -c(ID, total), 
    names_to = c('item', '.value'),
    names_pattern = '(.*)\\.(.*)'
    )
```

```
  ID    total item  text  score
  <chr> <int> <chr> <chr> <int>
1 Mark      1 i1    A         0
2 Mark      1 i2    B         1
3 Mary      1 i1    C         1
4 Mary      1 i2    D         0
5 John      1 i1    A         0
6 John      1 i2    B         1
7 Abby      2 i1    C         1
8 Abby      2 i2    B         1
```

Comment: Thanks, could you add to your response the explanation of what is happening in `names_pattern`? I see it works, but I don’t understand the syntax `’(.*)\\.(.*)’`

Comment: Please see my update!